# Disable keyboard navigation in a Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an inline Google Map that, when clicked, can be navigated through using the keyboard arrow keys. This doesn't allow a person to use the arrow keys to scroll the actual page unless they click somewhere else on the page first. Is there a way to disable this navigation by arrow keys?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

set the option `keyboardShortcuts` of the map to `false`

Comment: this prevents rotating with keyboard, not going back/forth

Comment: actually it disableds keyboard movement until the first map click, then it works again :(